# Reading stdout/stderr from an exec()'ed process in a daemon

Tags: c++, c, fork, exec, daemon

I have a daemon process where I need to fork()/exec() some new processes and then read the child processes stdout/stderr.

My problem is that the parent is a daemon where stdout and stderr are closed.  Is there anyway to do this?  Do I have to open a shell?

```
int status;
pipe(pipefd_stdout);
pipe(pipefd_stderr);

pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == 0)
{   
    close(pipefd_stdout[0]);    // close reading end in the child
    close(pipefd_stderr[0]);    // close reading end in the child

    dup2(pipefd_stdout[1], 1);  // send stdout to the pipe
    dup2(pipefd_stderr[1], 2);  // send stderr to the pipe

    execvpe(cmd, (char**)args, (char**)env);
}
else
{
    // parent ...

    waitpid(pid, &status, 0);

    close(pipefd_stderr[1]);  
    close(pipefd_stdout[1]);  
}
```

Comment: _"Do I have to open a shell?"_ No, build a pipe instead.

Comment: I have similar problem. Unfortunately I can't use pipe as you suggested because I'm using `system()` function. Is redirecting `stdout` to temporary file correct alternative?

Answer (score 0):

A shell wouldn't help here anyway. You need to create one or more pipes (depending in whether you want the output to stdout/stderr conflated into one stream or not) using `pipe()` and then `dup()` (or similar) and `close()` to put the appropriate file descriptors into place.  The call to `pipe()` precedes the `fork()`, the calls to `dup()` and `close()` come after.

Comment: @devin: you aren't closing enough pipe file descriptors.  If you `dup()` or `dup2()` a pipe to standard input, standard output or standard error, you should close _both_ ends of the pipe essentially always.  Assume you should do so until you come across a circumstance where you shouldn't — it won't happen soon.

Comment: I close the pipe in the parent (see edit).  Is there a way to close it for the child?  I've been under the impression that exec() won't return unless it errors so I'm not sure how I would even do this.